# Can i create folder on Android internal storage?

Tags: android, storage, directory, internal

Assume I'm dealing with a text editor application. I want to store created text files on a folder which will be in the phone or sdcard (from user choice). I just want to save files onto a folder on internal storage(phone). Am i able to create a folder on android internal storage from code and copy these files there? A folder which will not be private to my application or store under "/data/data/MyapplicationPackage/" and witch from the user could access(read)?
Any hint? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your requirement? Make files accessible without using your application (e.g., by mounting the SD card and accessing directly)? Making your app's data accessible to other apps? Something else?

Comment: Yes, make the folder(and files in) accessible without using my application. User may send that folder to another device by bluetooth or some other way. Or use an usb  connection to copy the folder to the pc,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To satisfy your requirement you can either:

1. Have your app's files and folders stored on external storage (SD card).
2. Provide some sort of 'export' feature letting users export their files and folders (possibly bundled in a zip file). If you use the `ACTION_SEND` you can let them send the exported files by email, save to Dropbox, etc. practically for free.
3. Make your data available via a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to hide the actual storage mechanism. Depending on the type of data, you might want to control access to that provider.

Comment: 1. Does this mean, my application will be installed on SD card? How could i deal with SD card less phone?

Comment: No, just the data files. Even if it doesn't have a physical SD card, it should have external storage which is shared among applications and can be access from a PC. Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory() for details.

Comment: 1. Ok. Did i misunderstand the 'external storage' concept and methods?
That doesn't necessary mean a physical SD card? 

2. Yes, already thought about it. For now I've three checkboxes to choose where to save the zip folder (phone storage, sd card, ftp server) and the first one is why i'm here (how to make a little folder on this place :D)

3. I'm not sure anymore about going so far. But thanks :)

Comment: Most newer phones have external storage implemented as a separate internal partition, not a physical SD card. It behaves exactly the same, except that you cannot physically remove it, of course. As for the general internal/external storage concept, you can think of it this way: internal=private, external=shared.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now, how did I specify both "external storage" and SD card?

Comment: An SD card is a form of external storage. You should use the API's in Environment to get the external storage folder, and you shouldn't care  about the concrete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can, but it does not meet your criteria.
It will be private, stored under /data/data/..., and will not be user accessible except via the application.  That is unless the user is rooted.

Comment: :( Is there an alternative or something that comes close to my criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html). You have many options to do that, and all depends on mounted names on your device. See APIs  getDir() to create a filepath for a private file.

Check also in which path the audio recorder application is writing its files, that solved for me since I could'nt get any private file working for lack of permitions.

You can always enter ADB in console mode, with "adb shell" and run a linux "mount" command to see all your mounted files, you'll need root access though.

Comment: Why is it so hard to make a simple folder on internal memory compare to external storage?

Comment: Sadly, there are tons of hard to do things in Android, I by myself I'm very used to that, scavenging blogs to find answers.

Comment: oh yeah. I dug for a long time before landing here. I'll try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I also was facing same problem. I wanted to create a folder in Internal Memory. I tried many code provided in stackoverflow itself. But non of those worked properly. So at last I gave the root directory own my own.

```
File newFolder = new File("/storage/emulated/0/", "Folder_Name");
```

This code worked absolutely fine for me.